# C# How to copy few columns schema from datatable using clone

Tags: c#, datatable

Is there any way to copy only few columns schema from a datatable using clone method? if not what is the best solution to copy few columns with schema from one datatable to another.

Comment: U can create a new table with only the columns u need

Comment: You should use, `DataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(false, columnsnamearray);`

Comment: @YograjGupta It's working... it copies including schema also?

Comment: @Nag I posted my comment as answer, If it answer your question, accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use,

```
DataTable newTable = dataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(false, columnsnamearray);
```

Comment: It's Wokring, is it contains same schema as parent table?